# Populating Textbox and DropdownLists

Tags: vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, webforms

I am having a hard time trying to populate a textbox, and two dropdown lists. What I am attempting to do is this: when the Company dropdownlist has been selected, it will display a grid of its respective values from a sqldatasource, which it does. Now the next step is once a selection from the company dropdown has been made, a textbox will display the membertype as well as the second dropdownlist. The third dropdown displays the groupid. All these three components have their outputs after a selection has been made. But I cannot seem to get the values to show. I also added code for clarification.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Partial Class companydropdown
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub BindDropDownList(DropdownList1 As DropDownList, query As String, text As String, value As String, defaultText As String)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Read sql server connection string from web.config file
        Dim sConstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ds17701ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(sConstr)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("tbl")

        Using Conn
            Conn.Open()
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName,CompanyID FROM CompanyList ORDER BY CompanyName", Conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
            'da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        'DropdownList1.DataSource = dt
        DropdownList1.DataTextField = "CompanyName"
        DropdownList1.DataValueField = "CompanyID"
        DropdownList1.DataBind()
        'DropdownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--"))
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Member_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        Dim sConstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ds17701ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(sConstr)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("tbl")

        Using Conn
            Conn.Open()
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName,CompanyID FROM CompanyList " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue & " ORDER BY CompanyName", Conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        'DropDownList2.DataSource = dt
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "MembershipStatus"
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "MemberTypeID"
        ' Bind sql server data into the Dropdown List
        DropDownList2.DataBind()
    Else
        DropDownList2.Items.Clear()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Group_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        Dim sConstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ds17701ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(sConstr)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("tbl")

        Using Conn
            Conn.Open()
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName,CompanyID FROM CompanyList " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue & " ORDER BY CompanyName", Conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        'DropDownList2.DataSource = dt
        DropDownList3.DataTextField = "GroupID"
        DropDownList3.DataValueField = "GroupID"
        ' Bind sql server data into the Dropdown List
        DropDownList3.DataBind()
    Else
        DropDownList3.Items.Clear()
    End If

End Sub



Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    DropDownList2.Enabled = False
    'DropDownList3.Items.Clear()
    DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", "0"))
    Dim stateId As Integer = Integer.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
    If stateId > 0 Then
        Dim query As String = String.Format("", stateId)
        BindDropDownList(DropDownList1, query, "CompanyName", "CompanyId", "")
        DropDownList3.Enabled = True
        DropDownList2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

[image: Populating Textbox and dropdowns]

Comment: You might want to add the appropriate tech tags and/or clear up the question.  `Winforms`, `WebForms` or whatever tags would make more sense than :"textbox" or "auto-pop"

Comment: What have you tried so far?? post some code...
Does the Member type and Group, are fixed values? are they loaded from an sql source?

Comment: For every dropdown list, they are loaded from an sqldatasource. So far, I have tried to bind the data from every dropdownlist. I posted the code in the problem for clarification's sake.